# Looking for a google apps or similar products for bug tracking

Tags: google-apps

I saw googlebugs and I would like to find something similar. Does anyone know of anything out there. I have been searching for a long time on the web but still did not find a product as good as [googlebugs](https://code.google.com/p/googlebugs/)

Answer (score 1):

You do know you can just go to https://code.google.com/ and create an account, then you can use all those features on your own project, right?

There are loads of other bug tracking tools:

Spiratest
Jira
Bugzilla etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have looked at jira etc but looking for something a little bit simpler. I will check out the link you gave me right now.

Comment: I checked this out but notice: Project Hosting
Project Hosting on Google Code provides a free collaborative development environment for open source projects.  The project I have is not open source :-(

Comment: Sure, but you did not mention that in your question. Here's a few more links to perhaps more suitable s/w http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/9-free-and-open-source-bug-tracking-softwares/

Comment: Can the bug tracking tools available in google developer be made available to a group of UAT testers? Do they need anything more than a google account?

Comment: I'd assume so, but these days I use bitbucket!